# Java regex to escape pipe

Tags: java, regex-group

I am trying to parse account no and balance from bank sms using java regex group. I am able to successfully parse account no but not able to get the balance as it is always getting null value maybe due to pipe

Sms I am trying to parse is :

```
Balances for Ac XXXXXXXX0000 on 16/12/2020 11:37:14 AM ISTTotal Avbl. Bal: INR|980310.28Avbl. Bal: INR 980310.28Linked FD bal: INR|0.0
```

Regex I am using is:

```
Balances for Ac (?groupname.+?) on 16/12/2020 11:37:14 AM ISTTotal Avbl. Bal: INR|980310.28Avbl. Bal: INR (?groupname[0-9.]+)Linked FD bal: INR|0.0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: "Escape pipe" well, have you tried escaping it?

Comment: Yes I tried using \\| but I think I am doing something wrong as it's not working

Comment: I suppose the missing angled brackets are because of problems with encoding on this site. Also, when using name groups, use unique names.

Comment: Language issue? E.g. you need to escape with \| or \\|.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Escape the pipe like you probably have already tried using a backslash `\\|`.
2. Your problem is with what comes next. It will only match for an amount of `0.0`.

Try this:

```
INR (?<groupname>[0-9.]+)Linked FD bal: INR\\|(?<amount>[0-9.]+)
```